Dataframe from PDF-file (no tables, only text)
I have pdf file with metodic information for laboratory works, I need to parse it to dataframe with columns Lab #, Lab content, page number. So for example at Lab 1, Lab content will be all text between Lab 1 and Lab 2. Laboratory works in file separated by keywords "Laboratory work [digit]"
I tried to do this with PyPDF2, but saved only content from current page which contain keyword
import PyPDF2
import pandas as pd
import re


def extract_lab_info(pdf_file):
    # Open the PDF file
    with open(pdf_file, 'rb') as file:
        reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(file)
        lab_contents = []
        start_flag = False
        start_keyword = 'Content'

        # Iterate through each page
        for page_num in range(len(reader.pages)):
            page = reader.pages[page_num]
            text = page.extract_text()
            if start_flag:
                # Find occurrences of "Lab #"
                lab_indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(text.splitlines()) if "Laboratory work" in x]

                # Extract lab content and page number
                for i, index in enumerate(lab_indices):
                    lab_number = text.splitlines()[index]
                    lab_number = re.search(r'{}\s+(\d+)'.format('Laboratory work'), lab_number).group(0)

                    if i == len(lab_indices) - 1:
                        lab_content = "\n".join(text.splitlines()[index + 1:])
                    else:
                        next_index = lab_indices[i + 1]
                        lab_content = "\n".join(text.splitlines()[index + 1:next_index])
                    lab_contents.append({'Lab #': lab_number, 'Lab Content': lab_content, 'Page Number': page_num + 1})
            elif start_keyword in text:
                start_flag = True


    return lab_contents

# Path to your PDF file
pdf_file_path = 'Metodic1.pdf'


# Extract lab information
lab_info = extract_lab_info(pdf_file_path)

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(lab_info)
# Display DataFrame
print(df)


Can you share your code part so we can help you to figured out how to solve your problem.

@MuhammedSamedÖzmen I share code

PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf.
